# Insert date without using scope or controller in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how can I insert a date in my html without using a scope or controller. I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<p>Sample text {{Date.now().toString() | date:'yyyy'}} sample text</p>
```

I also tried without .toString but doesnt work as well

Would be great if you could let me know how I can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not seeing any obvious way to achieve this. Why do you need to do it this way?

Comment: Angular templates don't support full javascript, it's not what they are designed for. You should use a controller for this.

Answer (score 2):

To solve that without a controller you can use a **custom directive** where you can just add a kind of div in the HTML and it will render the date.

with that you can do something like that:

HTML

```
<span date-now="MM/dd/yyyy"></span>
```

JS

```
.directive('dateNow', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return {
    link: function( $scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.text($filter('date')(new Date(), $attrs.dateNow));
    }
  };
}])
```

Result:

```
05/10/2016
```

[Custom directives - Angular reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Why don't you mark that answer as solved ? do you have problems yet ?